# boto3- regions names and service names

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

How can I get the list of all the regions for eg: `us-east-1`. How can I get the list of all the regions using boto3. **(I am not trying to get the available regions for a particular service as have been asked already)**

Also how can I get the names of all the services that AWS provides using boto3 so that I can use them later, when creating resources or clients later on.

I am asking this question because **when** **creating sessions or resources or client I have to specify these things and I don't know how to find the exact value to pass.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the regions, the closest you can get is [describe_regions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_regions):

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
response = [region['RegionName'] for region in ec2.describe_regions(AllRegions=True)['Regions']]

print(response)
```

which gives:

```
['af-south-1', 'eu-north-1', 'ap-south-1', 'eu-west-3', 'eu-west-2', 'eu-south-1', 'eu-west-1', 'ap-northeast-3', 'ap-northeast-2', 'me-south-1', 'ap-northeast-1', 'sa-east-1', 'ca-central-1', 'ap-east-1', 'ap-southeast-1', 'ap-southeast-2', 'eu-central-1', 'us-east-1', 'us-east-2', 'us-west-1', 'us-west-2']
```

For services - I don't think there is any API call for that. You could scrape them from [here](https://awspolicygen.s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/policygen.html), but this would not involve boto3.

Comment: i am wondering why are you using ec2 to get region names? i did a google search and it listed 25 aws regions however in the above output there are only 21 regions

Comment: @rimalroshan I does not show china and government regions, which are special. I use ec2 because this is the only API I know that provides such a list. I don't think you will find something better then his. If this is not enough, you will have to manually hard code all the regions in your program or scrape them from some AWS documentation website or other source.

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of services in AWS you can perform get_available_services of boto3 Session:

```
import boto3
boto_session = boto3.session.Session()
list_of_services = boto_session.get_available_services()

print(list_of_services)
```

which gives you a list of all available services in AWS

```
['accessanalyzer', 'account', 'acm', 'acm-pca', 'alexaforbusiness', 'amp', 'amplify', 'amplifybackend', 'apigateway', 'apigatewaymanagementapi', 'apigatewayv2', 'appconfig', 'appflow', 'appintegrations', 'application-autoscaling', 'application-insights', 'applicationcostprofiler', 'appmesh', 'apprunner', 'appstream', 'appsync', 'athena', 'auditmanager', 'autoscaling', 'autoscaling-plans', 'backup', 'batch', 'braket', 'budgets', 'ce', 'chime', 'chime-sdk-identity', 'chime-sdk-meetings', 'chime-sdk-messaging', 'cloud9', 'cloudcontrol', 'clouddirectory', 'cloudformation', 'cloudfront', 'cloudhsm', 'cloudhsmv2', 'cloudsearch', 'cloudsearchdomain', 'cloudtrail', 'cloudwatch', 'codeartifact', 'codebuild', 'codecommit', 'codedeploy', 'codeguru-reviewer', 'codeguruprofiler', 'codepipeline', 'codestar', 'codestar-connections', 'codestar-notifications', 'cognito-identity', 'cognito-idp', 'cognito-sync', 'comprehend', 'comprehendmedical', 'compute-optimizer', 'config', 'connect', 'connect-contact-lens', 'connectparticipant', 'cur', 'customer-profiles', 'databrew', 'dataexchange', 'datapipeline', 'datasync', 'dax', 'detective', 'devicefarm', 'devops-guru', 'directconnect', 'discovery', 'dlm', 'dms', 'docdb', 'ds', 'dynamodb', 'dynamodbstreams', 'ebs', 'ec2', 'ec2-instance-connect', 'ecr', 'ecr-public', 'ecs', 'efs', 'eks', 'elastic-inference', 'elasticache', 'elasticbeanstalk', 'elastictranscoder', 'elb', 'elbv2', 'emr', 'emr-containers', 'es', 'events', 'finspace', 'finspace-data', 'firehose', 'fis', 'fms', 'forecast', 'forecastquery', 'frauddetector', 'fsx', 'gamelift', 'glacier', 'globalaccelerator', 'glue', 'grafana', 'greengrass', 'greengrassv2', 'groundstation', 'guardduty', 'health', 'healthlake', 'honeycode', 'iam', 'identitystore', 'imagebuilder', 'importexport', 'inspector', 'iot', 'iot-data', 'iot-jobs-data', 'iot1click-devices', 'iot1click-projects', 'iotanalytics', 'iotdeviceadvisor', 'iotevents', 'iotevents-data', 'iotfleethub', 'iotsecuretunneling', 'iotsitewise', 'iotthingsgraph', 'iotwireless', 'ivs', 'kafka', 'kafkaconnect', 'kendra', 'kinesis', 'kinesis-video-archived-media', 'kinesis-video-media', 'kinesis-video-signaling', 'kinesisanalytics', 'kinesisanalyticsv2', 'kinesisvideo', 'kms', 'lakeformation', 'lambda', 'lex-models', 'lex-runtime', 'lexv2-models', 'lexv2-runtime', 'license-manager', 'lightsail', 'location', 'logs', 'lookoutequipment', 'lookoutmetrics', 'lookoutvision', 'machinelearning', 'macie', 'macie2', 'managedblockchain', 'marketplace-catalog', 'marketplace-entitlement', 'marketplacecommerceanalytics', 'mediaconnect', 'mediaconvert', 'medialive', 'mediapackage', 'mediapackage-vod', 'mediastore', 'mediastore-data', 'mediatailor', 'memorydb', 'meteringmarketplace', 'mgh', 'mgn', 'migrationhub-config', 'mobile', 'mq', 'mturk', 'mwaa', 'neptune', 'network-firewall', 'networkmanager', 'nimble', 'opensearch', 'opsworks', 'opsworkscm', 'organizations', 'outposts', 'panorama', 'personalize', 'personalize-events', 'personalize-runtime', 'pi', 'pinpoint', 'pinpoint-email', 'pinpoint-sms-voice', 'polly', 'pricing', 'proton', 'qldb', 'qldb-session', 'quicksight', 'ram', 'rds', 'rds-data', 'redshift', 'redshift-data', 'rekognition', 'resource-groups', 'resourcegroupstaggingapi', 'robomaker', 'route53', 'route53-recovery-cluster', 'route53-recovery-control-config', 'route53-recovery-readiness', 'route53domains', 'route53resolver', 's3', 's3control', 's3outposts', 'sagemaker', 'sagemaker-a2i-runtime', 'sagemaker-edge', 'sagemaker-featurestore-runtime', 'sagemaker-runtime', 'savingsplans', 'schemas', 'sdb', 'secretsmanager', 'securityhub', 'serverlessrepo', 'service-quotas', 'servicecatalog', 'servicecatalog-appregistry', 'servicediscovery', 'ses', 'sesv2', 'shield', 'signer', 'sms', 'sms-voice', 'snow-device-management', 'snowball', 'sns', 'sqs', 'ssm', 'ssm-contacts', 'ssm-incidents', 'sso', 'sso-admin', 'sso-oidc', 'stepfunctions', 'storagegateway', 'sts', 'support', 'swf', 'synthetics', 'textract', 'timestream-query', 'timestream-write', 'transcribe', 'transfer', 'translate', 'voice-id', 'waf', 'waf-regional', 'wafv2', 'wellarchitected', 'wisdom', 'workdocs', 'worklink', 'workmail', 'workmailmessageflow', 'workspaces', 'xray']
```